# How to find the variation of vielbeins?

Tags: general-relativity, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

It is in a course on GR that I saw the following formula
$$\delta e_a^\mu=(\lambda^\nu\partial_\nu e_a^\mu-e_a^\nu\partial_\nu\lambda^\mu)+\lambda_a^b e_b^\mu.$$
It stands for the variation of the vielbein $e_a^\mu$. How'd it happen? Why don't we talk about the covariant derivative of the vielbein?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're looking for? This looks like an arbitrary (infinitesimal) diff+local Lorentz transformation. How does this relate to the covariant derivative? Of course it can be talked about...

Comment: We are going to derive the Einstein field equations from the perspective of gauge symmetry. Ultimately, we need to arrive at the Einstein-Hilbert action. What I have written in the question is just a small step (but it really confuses me).

Comment: It's really not a good idea to specify a particular variation in getting the equations of motion from an action. I can recommend looking in the Supergravity book by Freedman and Proeyen for the details of the vielbein/spin connection formulation.

Comment: Thank you for recommending me a good book on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite confusing what do the $\lambda$'s in your equation mean. It seems to me a hybrid of Eq. (12.5.11) and (12.5.32) in Weinberg's GR. If so, then the terms have the following meanings.

The second term $\lambda^{a}_{\;b}e_a^{\;\mu}$ is the infinitesimal change under a local Lorentz transformation of vierbeins. Under local Lorentz transformation satisfying
$$\eta_{ab}\Lambda^a_{\;c}\Lambda^b_{\;d}=\eta_{cd},$$
vierbeins transform as
$$e_b^{\;\mu}\to\Lambda^{a}_{\;b}e_a^{\;\mu}.$$
Written $\Lambda^{a}_{\;b}$ as $\delta^{a}_{\;b}+\lambda^{a}_{\;b}$ gives you the second term.

While the first term is a coordinate change, or Lie derivative, of vierbeins under ${x'}^\mu=x^\mu-\lambda^\mu$.
$$\delta e_a^{\;\mu}(x)
=\frac{\partial(x^\mu-\lambda^\mu)}{\partial x^\nu}
    e_a^{\;\nu}(x)-e_a^{\;\mu}(x-\lambda)
=\lambda^\nu\partial_\nu e_a^{\;\mu}-e_a^{\;\nu}\partial_\nu \lambda^\mu.$$
Or written in Lie derivative
$$\delta e_a^{\;\mu}=\mathcal{L}_{\lambda}e_a^{\;\mu}
=\lambda^\nu\partial_\nu e_a^{\;\mu}-e_a^{\;\nu}\partial_\nu \lambda^\mu.$$